Replacement for TPS51217
I need a replacement for TPS51217. I don't have a spare one available. But I do have TPS51218. They are only different on pin 5.
How to use TPS51218 instead of TPS51217?

Please review the datasheets. These two devices have slightly different functionality, particularly at pin 5 from both devices. Ask Texas Instruments or a third party seller (e.g. Digikey, Mouser, etc.) about an alternative part with the same footprint and pinout functionality.

TPS51217 works on fixed freq (340KHz) while TPS51218 has variable frequency to be set at pin 5(RF) including 340KHz. TPS51217 pin 5 (TRAN) is used to vary the output voltage up and down. Wouldn't it be possible to use TPS51218, setting RF @340KHz by connecting a 200Kohm resistor, the output voltage should remain stable as the min output of TPS51217. Wouldn't this setup work?

They (TPS51217) are in-stock at TI.com for $1.37, can't you just order one?  They'll also send a free sample (or a few) if you request it.
